# Erro "Unknown column" em consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

<sub>Código:</sub>

```
(SELECT
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO,

   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES,
   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO,

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = 1
WHERE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
    CASE
        WHEN TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO
    END AS ACRESCIMO, 

   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES,
   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO,

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO
INNER JOIN TB_INGREDIENTES ON TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE  
WHERE TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = 1)
```

**Erro: <sub>(1)</sub>**
`Unknown column 'TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES' in 'field list'`

**Tabelas:**

<sub>**TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES**</sub>

[image: tb_produtos_ingredientes]

<sub>**TB_PRODUTOS**</sub>

[image: tb_produtos]

<sub>**TB_INGREDIENTES**</sub>

[image: tb_ingredientes]

Queria fazer um `select` com essas colunas, e sim, elas existem na tabela. Mas no primeiro `select`, antes do `UNION ALL`, se eu colocar os campos da tabela `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` e `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO`, o [MySQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), retorna aquele **Erro <sub>(1)</sub>**. Agora, se eu trocar aqueles campos, por qualquer número, a consulta é executada normal.

<sub>Código da consulta executada com qualquer numero</sub>

```
(SELECT
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO,

   20, -- Colocando qualquer número
   20, -- Colocando qualquer número

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = 1
WHERE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
    CASE
        WHEN TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO
    END AS ACRESCIMO, 

   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES,
   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO,

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO
INNER JOIN TB_INGREDIENTES ON TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE  
WHERE TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = 1)
```

**Por que isso ocorre?**

**Edição**

Preciso do result assim:

[image: Acrescimos]

Repare que os grifados em `amarelo`, são os acréscimos.

Eles são definidos pela coluna `acréscimos` pelo número `1`. Então todo registro que estiver o número `1` na coluna, é um acréscimo.

Comment: Já viu se a coluna `ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` existe na tabela `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você precisa de um join na primeira consulta, tente assim:

```
(SELECT
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO,

   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES,
   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO,

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = 1
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES ON TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO
WHERE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
   TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.INGREDIENTE,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_TOTAL,
   TB_INGREDIENTES.FLAG,
    CASE
        WHEN TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE TB_INGREDIENTES.ACRESCIMO
    END AS ACRESCIMO, 

   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES,
   TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO,

   TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.TIPO_PRODUTO,
   TB_PRODUTOS.PRECO_PRODUTO
FROM `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` 
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO
INNER JOIN TB_INGREDIENTES ON TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE = TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE  
WHERE TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = 1)
```

Não exatamente como você quer retornar os dados mas talvez:

```
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES ON TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO
```

Deva ser:

```
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES ON TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO AND TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE = TB_INGREDIENTES.ID_INGREDIENTE
```

Ajuda na query:

```
SELECT 
    PI.*,
    I.*,
    P.*
FROM 
    TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES PI 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_PRODUTO P
    ON PI.ID_PRODUTO = P.ID_PRODUTO
INNER JOIN 
    TB_INGREDIENTE I
    ON PI.ID_INGREDIENTE = I.ID_INGREDIENTE
```

Veja se com essa query retorna todos os dados, e ai você filtra e coloca o where onde vc achar que deve.

Comment: Eu queria que retornasse o `produto` com seus `ingredientes`, mais os acrescimos. No seu `select`, está retornando o produto e todos os `ingredientes` inserido na tabela. Adicionando o 2º `INNER JOIN`, ele retorna os `ingredientes` relacionado ao produto, mas não traz os acrescimos contido na tabela `ingredientes`. Que não é o meu objetivo.

Comment: Troca todos os inner joins por left join pra ver se resolve.

Comment: @Exception, acredito que o seu problema de Unknown column field tenha sido resolvido. Então a resposta do Joao Paulo está correta.

Comment: É agora é repensar a lógica da sua query na verdade. Vou ver se te ajudo aqui.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, Resolveu em partes rs. Agora as colunas `ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES` e `QUANTIDADE_INGREDIENTE_USADO` estão retornando `NULL`

Comment: Coloquei uma query que traz todos os resultados. Ve se ela traz as informações que você quer. E se trouxer coisa demais é só adicionar algum where.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Certo! Mas é que preciso no `UNION ALL` para listar os `ingredientes` que são `acréscimos` e os `ingredientes` que são do `produto` e não são `acréscimo`. Entendeu?

Comment: O que você chama de acréscimos? Que informação que o campo acrescimo fornece?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo vou editar a pergunta para você ver como eu quero a resposta da consulta.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Editado!

Comment: Beleza, mas só pra ficar claro. Esquecendo o banco de dados. Quando você diz que um ingrediente é um acréscimo, o que isso significa? Que ele foi adicionado ao produto?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Que ele pode ser adicionado ao produto. Estou fazendo assim pra mostrar eles: `if(isAcrescimo){ adicionarCheckBoxAcrescimo()}` (é apenas a logica).

Comment: @JoaoPaulo acho que entendi o que está acontecendo. As colunas que eu disse anteriormente estão retornando `NULL` por que não estão "atrelados" ao produto. Quando tem algum relacionamento entre `ingredientes` e `produtos`, ele retorna um valor normal, mas quando não há relacionamento, ele retorna `NULL` em vez de suas informações.

Comment: Sugiro que você crie outra questão explicando bem o retorno que você deseja. Assim como mostrou aqui complementando a primeira pergunta, mas como a questão do null já foi solucionada acho que se você separar outras pessoas também poderão ajudar na sua outra dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque você está passando uma constante ao invés de uma referência.

Ao invés de você estar falando: me devolva o valor que está presente na coluna `TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES.ID_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES`. Você está falando, me devolva `20`